# Hidden Javascript Button on larger screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I am new to Javascript but have the following code taken from W3 How to Scroll Back to Top Button: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_to_top.asp

I'd like to remove the button on a min-width media query (for example min-width:600px) - is that possible? Sorry, I am sure this is really basic, thanks.

Code

```js
var mybutton = document.getElementById("top-button");

// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

```css
#top-button {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0.75rem;
  right: 0.75rem;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: #1A936F;
  color: #f3e9d2;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="top-button" title="Go to top">Top</button>
```

Comment: What should happen if the window is 2000px wide, and the user resizes it to 400px? What should happen in the reverse situation, from 400px to 2000px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`window.innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth) property.

Something like,

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  if (window.innerWidth <= 600) {
    scrollFunction();
  }
};
```

Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/codeandcloud/sezk0j74/

Comment: Thanks - where in the script (specifically) would I add that code please?

Comment: Change this line `window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};` to the above function.

Comment: window.onscroll = function () { if (window.screen.width <= 600) {
            scrollFunction();
        }
        };

Comment: I just seem to have lost the Top Button on all screen sizes. It's not there at all?

Comment: you want the scroll top to work when the width is greater than 600px or lesser?

Comment: Less than. I do not want it at all over 600px. But I do want it at screen sizes less than 600px. Thanks

Comment: Logic seems correct. Try with `availWidth` better use that

Comment: Thanks, but the button just disappears on all screen sizes!

Comment: window.onscroll = function () {
            if (window.screen.availWidth <= 600) {
            scrollFunction()
            }
        };

Comment: updated function to `window.innerWidth` and provided a sample

Comment: Worked - thank you! I really appreciate your time to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mybutton = document.getElementById("top-button");
var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)");

// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
    if (x.matches) {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
  else if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20){
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

Here, This should work!
Basically, you can use window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)").matches to check screen size. Then you can add js code to make button display none.